# Best way to move one VPS from one provider to another?

Tags: linux, vps, xen, kvm-virtualization, cloud-hosting

I have a VPS server (Xen based) purchased from one provider, now I want to move the server to another (kvm based)

What are the best way to do so? I really don't want to re-install the whole system, do the configurations again..

While I can afford the downtime, what are the safest way for lazy people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall your apps and move the data.

Even if both VPS providers are willing to work together to help you on this, convert a Xen VM to run on a KVM host is so much trouble that it's not worth it.